# Unable to render automatic slideshow with react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create an automatic slideshow in react, using [react-slideshow](https://github.com/andela-foladeji/react-slideshow). I'm very new to react and have just begun. I got this code from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slideshow-image).

```
import React from 'react';
import { Fade } from 'react-slideshow-image';
const images = [
  './img/p1.png',
  './img/p1.png',
  './img/p1.png'
];

const Slideshow = () => {
return (
    <Fade
      images={images}
      duration="5000"
      transitionDuration="1000"/>
   )
}
```

What I am not getting is how to make this slideshow actually render. What I have done is called this function from inside a component in the same file i.e.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      {Slideshow();}
    </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

This is not rendering any slideshow or image, about which I'm not too surprised. The function is running. I console logged something and it got logged on the console. The rest of the page (I have other divs not shown here) is rendered and there is no error thrown. How to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems wrong in this code.

1. try defining Slideshow() function inside app component.
2. make a call like  "{ this.Slideshow }".
3. Check by removing "./" in image path. (Try..)

Also check the path of image. Sometime they refer to public folder outside the src folder. maybe public/images/img.png

Comment: Tried points 1 and 2 before posting. Same result. Will try point 3 now but if path was wrong what I would have got should be 'module not found'. Thank you, though.

Comment: Just use <Fade /> with required props. Otherwise file a issue in github. That package is not that mature. I use slick slider which work without any problems

Comment: I am trying to use <Slide /> actually, not <Fade />

Answer (score 0):

`Slideshow` is a React component, so you need to render it using JSX, not invoke the function:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Slideshow/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Doing that gives the following error: 'Slideshow' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef. How is it a component when there is no "class Slideshow extends react.component" and it has been defined as an arrow function?

Comment: It is a functional component. See https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components

Comment: The reason `Slideshow` is not defined is something else. Are both code sections in the same file ? If not use `export default Slideshow` at the bottom of file in which Slideshow is defined.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same file. And I am still unable to make it render. The function is running but there is no sign of the slideshow on screen.

Comment: can you share a working pen or repo so that we can debug ?